# Get result from 2 date range and personstatus

Tags: c#, mysql

i have one questions.Im trying to get result from 2 date range and person status,mysql table have 3 column:id,Date,personstatus.
My table schema and example query have to this link: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dfde3/2

But this query is get result Min id in 2017-07-03 - personstatus='i' and Max id in 2017-07-03 - personstatus='o'.(this query is get true result but it is for 1 date range 2017-07-03,im trying 2 date range example 2017-07-03   : 2017-07-07)
How to get example from 2 date range get min id and max.
Example:

Min id in 2017-07-03,personstatus='i' , Max id in 2017-07-03,personstatus='o',

Min id in 2017-07-05,personstatus='i' , Max id in 2017-07-05,personstatus='o',

Min id in 2017-07-07,personstatus='i' , Max id in 2017-07-07,personstatus='o'

If this is not possible with sql query how to get this result from c# WPF to gridView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the following query should give you the result.

```
SELECT ta.id as minID, ta._date as minDate, tb.id as maxID, tb._date as maxDate
FROM
(SELECT * FROM t t1
JOIN
(Select MIN(_date) as minDate From t Where personstatus='i' GROUP BY DATE(_date)) t2
ON t1._date=t2.minDate) ta
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM t t3
JOIN
(Select MAX(_date) as maxDate From t Where personstatus='o' GROUP BY DATE(_date)) t4
ON t3._date=t4.maxDate) tb
ON DATE(ta._date)=DATE(tb._date)
```

A lot of joins and I'm not sure if this is the best option, but it works with your test data as expected.

The result is

```
minID minDate maxID maxDate
1 2017-07-03T10:00:00Z 4 2017-07-03T17:40:27Z 
5 2017-07-05T09:10:22Z 8 2017-07-05T17:50:19Z 
9 2017-07-07T09:50:19Z 11 2017-07-07T17:50:19Z
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben this is my result and answer,but im testing this date example ('2017-07-09 09:51:19','i'),
(13,'2017-07-09 09:51:19','o')  2 datetime range is equal but first is person status i , second is person status o,displaying result is not correctly.This is my table and query:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/184d1/1

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is. Could you give me a deeper explanation?